# XSLT 'apply-templates' and 'apply-templates with mode' in a single go

Tags: xml, xslt, apply-templates

I am trying to use apply-templates and apply-templates with mode like explained in the below example:

My input xml looks like:

```
<catalog>
<product dept="aaa">
    <number>111</number>
    <name>cap</name>
    <color>blue</color>
</product>
<product dept="bbb">
    <number>222</number>
    <name>bat</name>
    <color>white</color>
</product>
<product dept="ccc">
    <number>333</number>
    <name>bag</name>
    <color>red</color>
</product>
```

Now I am trying with the below shown xslt to remove the product element with dept=bbb but it doesn't work. The same input xml appears in the output. I know I can achieve my desired result by removing the mode attribute on the last template but I am trying to understand why it doesn't work in the way I'm trying here.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="modXml">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="remove" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($modXml)/*" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node( ) | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/catalog/product[@dept='bbb']" mode="remove" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone please explain how the XSLT processor is running the transformation here..?

Thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
<xsl:variable name="modXml">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="remove" />
</xsl:variable>
```

When you do the first:

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

you are applying the *identity transform* template to **all** nodes (recursively) in the document. Once this is done, the variable already contains a copy of the entire document. Nothing you will do from this point on will change that.

Then, when you do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="remove" />
```

you are **adding** to the variable's existing *result-tree-fragment*. As it happens, the template applied does not actually add anything - but neither does it remove anything from the already existing result. There is no way to do so.

Comment: So does it mean that any subsequent xsl:apply-templates after the first xsl:apply-templates will not have any effect inside a variable declaration?  On trying this:    <xsl:variable name="modXml">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="remove" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:variable>   also gives the same result as my initial code. As per your saying, it should remove the product tag with dept="bbb" on applying the first xsl:apply-templates and then ignore the second xsl:apply-templates, right..?

Comment: No. A template does not really "remove" anything. That's just a metaphor. A template writes (or doesn't write) to the result tree, independent of any other template. In order to have the "removing" effect, you must have (at least) two templates: a general one that copies everything, and a specific one that doesn't copy certain nodes. When you apply them **together** (and in the same mode), then the more specific template takes precedence and the general template **is not applied** to the specific nodes.  In your case, there are two stages: first copy everything, then don't copy something.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, did you notice that I reversed the order of xsl:apply-templates (i.e. with 'mode' is written first and then the generic one) in my second attempt?

Comment: @Lokesh Yes, I did notice that. It makes no difference. What you do here has also two stages: first, you copy nothing. Then you copy everything. The order does not matter. You must apply the templates in such way that the specific template **overrides** the general one, so that it is not applied to the specific nodes and doesn't copy them.